# AVPlayer starts to reproduce a video after a long delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, ios10

Delay is about 10 seconds.
Snippet of my code. It's  *.m file of HomeController:

```
@interface HomeController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
@implementation HomeController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
}
- (IBAction)watchDemoToggle:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blahblahblah.com/demo.mp4"];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    if(playerItem)
    {
        AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        self.playerViewController.player = player;
        [self.playerViewController.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
        [self.playerViewController setShowsPlaybackControls:NO];
        [self presentViewController:self.playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{
            [self.playerViewController.player play];
            self.playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
        }];
    }
}

#pragma mark - KVO
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
            AVPlayerStatus status = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"status = %ld", (long)status);
        }
}
```

I added KVO and got result that after click play player status is AVPlayerStatusUnknown. After that it is not changing despite the fact that the video is reproducing.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling property of AVPlayer to false in order to start playback immediately.

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false;
```

But if sufficient content is not available for playing then player might stall.

for more details please refer this Apple documentation.

[avplayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1643482-automaticallywaitstominimizestal)

Comment: A lot of thanks!! I don't understand why i did'nt find it himself.. But what do you think about this: I added KVO and got result that after click play player status is AVPlayerStatusUnknown. After that it is not changing despite the fact that the video is reproducing. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: AVPlayerStatusUnknown  indicates that the status of the player is not yet known because it has not tried to load new media resources for playback.Can you check with local URL? If issue exists.

Comment: The property is only available for iOS 10 and above is there any other solution to support iOS 9 as well